# How to receive 2 different values from one Subscribe?

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

Is there any option to get two values from one subscription? The first being all profile data and the second is just the favorite data filtering by name.
I want to use fewest number of firebase request as I can.

the db structure:

```
profile{
        uid{
            name,
            age,
            favorite{
                     name,
                     uid,
                    }
            }
        }
```

this the component code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.db.getDataObj("/Profile/" + this.uid).subscribe(res =>{
      console.log("Profile Result");
      console.log(res);
    });
    this.db.getDataObj("/Profile/" + this.uid/favorite).subscribe(res =>{
      console.log("Profile Result");
      console.log(res);
    });
```

this the service code:

```
  getDataObj(objpath:string){
    this.objRef = this.db.object(objpath);
    this.obj = this.objRef.valueChanges();
    return this.obj;
   }
```

Comment: Favorites are a nested object in Profiles. You should obtain them directly from the first request. Except if I had misunderstood your question.

Comment: the more correct question is if I can use map or filter (operator) to do manipulation on the data I get from the db and allocation this to one variable. and meanwhile, get the non - manipulting data in the same subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. 
One request will always return one response.

However, looking at your database structure you should only need one request.

```
this.db.getDataObj("/Profile/" + this.uid).subscribe(res =>{
   console.log("Profile Result");
   console.log(res);
});
```

The "res" here should contain the complete profile object (including the "favorite" object).

If you still want to make this code shorter/cleaner you can look into creating a "zip" observable. More info [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html).

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct then please create the following interfaces:

```
interface Profile{
    uid:uid;
}

interface uid{

    name:string;
    age:number;
    favourite:favourite;
}

interface favourite{

    name:string;
    uid:string;
}
```

and then use the following in your service:

```
getDataObj(objpath:string):Observable<Profile>{
    return this.http.get<Profile>(objpath);
}
```

and then read the favourite value like:

```
this.db.getDataObj("/Profile/" + this.uid).subscribe(res<Profile> =>{
    console.log("Profile Result");
    console.log(res.uid.favourite);
});
```

If possible try to get data related to a uid favourites with the profile for that uid, this way you will have only one service call to get all the data. If this call is not data heavy, I think this is the way to go. Otherwise looking at long term perspective if the amount of data you will receive in Profile service http call is supposed to increase then use separate http calls for getting profile and favourite data for one uid.

This is the first time I am answering a question on this forum so please feel free to provide me feedback on my answer.